# What determines how many hearts I get?

Tags: ketzals-corridors

I have just started playing Ketzal's Corridors on the 3DS, and I can't for the life of me figure out what determines how many hearts I will get in a level.

I know it has something to do with combos, but I got a 19 combo on two different play throughs in one level and got two different heart amounts.

What else is there that affects the heart count? I want to get my heart count as high as possible so I can get all the gold level badges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a matter of combos, it's a matter of actual hearts you're collecting. If you take a look at the holes you're passing through, you'll sometimes notice the hearts you're looking for, you have to touch them with your tile to collect them.

EDIT: I did a little more research, and indeed combos count. What also counts, though, is the time it takes to do every trick. Accelerating yields a greater score, so it can be this the reason you're seeing the differences you noticed.

Comment: How then can I complete a level collecting every heart I see and end up with vastly different totals on two run throughs?

Comment: @DerpyHooves I did a little more research, and it seems I was wrong. I've updated the answer whit what I've found.

Comment: I wondered if that was the case! So combos and speed and hearts all count. No wonder I struggle!